# (image, mask) pair do not match one another in a semantic segmentation task

Tags: python, pytorch, dataset

I am writing a simple custom DataLoader (which I will add more features to later) for a segmentation dataset but the (image, mask) pair I return using `__getitem()__` method are different; the returned mask belongs to a different image than the one which is returned. My directory structure is `/home/bohare/data/images` and `/home/bohare/data/masks` .

Following is the code I have:

```
import torch
from torch.utils.data.dataset import Dataset
from PIL import Image
import glob
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class CustomDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, folder_path):
        
        self.img_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(folder_path,'images','*.png'))
        self.mask_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(folder_path,'masks','*.png'))
    
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        
        image = Image.open(self.img_files[index])
        mask = Image.open(self.mask_files[index])
        
        return image, mask
    
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.img_files)
```

```
data = CustomDataset(folder_path = '/home/bohare/data')
len(data)
```

This code correctly gives out the total size of the dataset.

But when I use:
`img, msk = data.__getitem__(n)` where n is the index of any (image, mask) pair and I plot the image and mask, they do not correspond to one another.

How can I modify/what can I add to the code to make sure the (image, mask) pair are returned correctly? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are they saved by the same name? What is the layout of the dataset in the directories?

Comment: As I mentioned in the post, the images are stored together in `home/bohare/data/images` and masks in `home/bohare/data/masks`. And yes, they are saved by the same names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`glob.glob` is returing it without order, [`glob.glob` calls internally `os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir):

> os.listdir(path) Return a list containing the names of the entries in
> the directory given by path. The list is in arbitrary order. It does
> not include the special entries '.' and '..' even if they are present
> in the directory.

To solve it, you can just sort both so that the order will be the same:

```
self.img_files = sorted(glob.glob(os.path.join(folder_path,'images','*.png')))
self.mask_files = sorted(glob.glob(os.path.join(folder_path,'masks','*.png')))
```

Comment: I pressed accept straight away but it wouldn't let me saying I must wait five minutes. I will accept it.